# Angularjs filter on clicks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I stumble upon the following problem
I create some buttons with ng-repeat and I want them to filter my list upon clicking one of them.The problem is that the list doesn't filter
Buttons :

```
<div ng-repeat="i in links">
   <a  href="" ng-click=" search = i.title " > {{i.title }}  </a> 
</div>

<div ng-repeat="i in links | filter: search">
   <p>{{i.names}}</p>     
</div>
```

But if I do something like this , the list is filtered properly

```
<a ng-click="search = 'music' ">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of quirks of Javascript's inheritance. Basically wrap your primitives in a object (in plunk below, the `custom` obj). Ng-repeat creates its own scope for each iteration.. so `search` is created for every scope, instead of sharing between the iterations.

Check out this plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GdTbpR1EBC1tPO8Fnq6c?p=preview

`<a href="" ng-click="custom.search=i.name;">`

`<div ng-repeat="i in links | filter: custom.search">`

And go through this post to get a better understanding on angular scopes.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function instead of messing scripts with markup:

```
$scope.filterLinks = function(title){
    $scope.search = title;
};
```

Then bind it:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in links">
   <a  href="" ng-click="filterLinks(i.title)" > {{i.title }}  </a> 
</div>
```